# How to construct X_train and Y_train for input to Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to solve an image labeling problem using keras. Each picture can have any number of labels from 0 to n, where n is the total number of distinct labels. I believe this is a  multiple independent binary classification problem.

I have a bunch of photos of multiple sizes, all jpegs, in a single folder. I have my Y_train labels as a sparse matrix.

- My problem is: how to combine the photos into a single object that keras will like.

I have thought about using `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` but I understand that this generates y labels automatically from the folder structure which is not relevant for my problem.

Thanks for any thoughts anyone might have...

Comment: You probably need to write your own generator, which yields a dictionary  `batch_dict={'inputLayerName' : X_train, 'outputLayerName' : Y_train}`, where `input/outputLayerName` should be the same as the one you used to define your network input/output, i.e. `net_in = Input(shape=(xxx), name='inputLayerName')`.

Comment: Actually the output of generator is just a tuple: `(x_train,y_train)`, being `x_train.shape=(batch_size,side1,side2,channels)` and `y_train.shape=(batch_size,classes)`